# How does laravel model relationships work in core?

Tags: laravel, function, oop, relationships, brackets

Consider this example

```
class SomeClass extends Model{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
$instance = SomeClass::findOrFail(1);
$user = $instance->user;
```

how do laravel know(i mean in core) that $instance->user (without brackets) return related model?

Comment: Very broad but in short, It's resolved by `__get()` accessor from `Model.php`. Check the source code.

Comment: Yes. Laravel’s source code is open source. You could have looked into this yourself: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1260

Comment: Its magic (functions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, whenever you try to access a property from a model, the `__get` [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) is invoked and it's something like the following:

```php
public function __get($key)
{
    return $this->getAttribute($key);
}
```

As you can see that, the `__get` magic method calls another user defined method (`getAttribute`) which is something like the following:

```php
public function getAttribute($key)
{
    if (! $key) {
        return;
    }

    // If the attribute exists in the attribute array or has a "get" mutator we will
    // get the attribute's value. Otherwise, we will proceed as if the developers
    // are asking for a relationship's value. This covers both types of values.
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->attributes) ||
        $this->hasGetMutator($key)) {
        return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
    }

    // Here we will determine if the model base class itself contains this given key
    // since we do not want to treat any of those methods are relationships since
    // they are all intended as helper methods and none of these are relations.
    if (method_exists(self::class, $key)) {
        return;
    }

    return $this->getRelationValue($key);
}
```

In this case (for relation), the last line `return $this->getRelationValue($key);` is responsible for retrieving a relationship. Keep reading the source code, track each function calls and you'll get the idea. Start from `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php::__get` method. Btw, this code is taken from latest version of `Laravel` but ultimately the process is same.

**Short summary**: Laravel at first checks if the property/`$kay` being accessed is a property of a model or if it's an accessor method defined in the model itself then it simply returns that property otherwise it keeps further checking and if it founds a method defined in the model using that name (property/`$kay`) then it simply returns the relationship.